# google sheets: custom formatting basing on cell below

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I have column "start of the period" with dates like

```
2014-01-01
2014-01-07
2014-02-01
2024-02-12
```

and so on; I want cell with start of the current period to be highlighted, so I tried custom formatting formula

`=AND(TODAY() >= R[0]C[0]; TODAY() < R[1]C[0])`

and it doesn't work.  Is it even possible in new sheets without custom onEdit() script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Use this in the custom formatting formula for the 1st cell

```
=and(today()>A1,today()<A2)
```

Google spreadsheets automatically changes the reference as you move down the row. So for the next row, the condition would become `=and(today()>A2,today()<A3)`.

Interestingly, if you check the conditional formatting formula, it still displays the former formula, but works just fine. Check [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18IjGrT4l_z46AMz0c-8-XZO6lkmVbhCbW7rmd0dXLrk/edit#gid=0).